# g++ - warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++14, libstdc++

I've following program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int i {0};
    std::string str {"Hello World"};
    std::cout << i << " : " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with g++ I got following error.
I'm using g++ 5.4. `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

I want to know what is the standard way to compile program in `g++` using `std::C++14` with necessary flags.

Thanks in Advance.

Update:

I've done it with following: `g++ ./ex01.cpp -o ex01.out -std=c++14 -Wall -o2`

Comment: *"I'm totally noob in C++."* does not excuse your inability to google stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile with the flag:

`-std=c++14`

Comment: I've done it with following `g++ ./ex01.cpp -o ex01.out -std=c++14 -Wall -o2`